# SSIS Master package gives The specified schema name either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it error but child package runs

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a master package which calls 2 child packages (execute package task) within same SSIS project. The child package runs successfully with no errors however when it returns to the master package, it gives error:

> The specified schema name (dbo) either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it

None of my statements reference the DBO schema, they all reference the schema I have permission to use.

I'm using Visual Studio 19

Comment: Somewhere there is a reference to `dbo` that you are missing.   Since we can't see your code, we can't help you find it.

Comment: You need to check your passing parameter value to child package. Check package level security of parent and child. Check your sql server connection of parent and child.

Comment: @TabAlleman I'm stumped- I went through every single SQL task and the connection managers and see nothing related to DBO, with every table containing my schema. I wonder if it's hidden within SSIS to me.

Comment: Open a code view of your package and search for the string "dbo".   Check to see if it's used in a view, function, constraint, trigger, anything else.

Comment: Unfortunately, dbo not found in either the parent or child package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:
The connection manager was erasing itself when opening the SSIS solution file, however the packages ran flawlessly when opening the project file (.dtproj) instead of the (.sln) file. I believe it has something to do with the connection manager being project level.